# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

hi i got some error on my code i cant figure it out, i have tried many step but its stay still, the data i call in provider is working but its still null in the page this is the code

this is my menu model

```
import 'package:kavarna/pages/models/gallery_model.dart';

class MenuModel {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  double? price;
  String? description;
  CategoryModel? category;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;
  List<GalleryModel>? gallery;

  MenuModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.description,
    this.category,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.gallery,
  });

  MenuModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    price = double.parse(json['price'].toString());
    description = json['description'];
    category = CategoryModel.fromJson(json['category']);
    gallery = json['gallery']
        .map<GalleryModel>((gallery) => GalleryModel.formJson(json))
        .toList();
    createdAt = DateTime.parse(json['created_at']);
    updatedAt = DateTime.parse(json['updated_at']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'price': price,
      'description': description,
      'category': category?.toJson(),
      'gallery': gallery?.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
      'created_at': createdAt,
      'updated_at': updatedAt,
    };
  }
}
```

and this is my provider

```
import 'package:kavarna/pages/models/menu_model.dart';
import 'package:kavarna/pages/services/menu_service.dart';

class MenuProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<MenuModel> _menuries = [];

  List<MenuModel> get menuries => _menuries;

  set menuries(List<MenuModel> menuries) {
    _menuries = menuries;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> getMenus() async {
    try {
      List<MenuModel> menuries = await MenuService().getMenu();
      _menuries = menuries;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

idk wheres the problem is but its still shown error like the title i post, i try to comment the print(e); in my provider its gone but its still shown if im not the error is like on this photo

[image: error result]

for more the detail i got and error in the category_model is there a wrong code i wrote ?

```
class CategoryModel {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  CategoryModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  CategoryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mapping the wrong variable here :

```dart
.map<GalleryModel>((gallery) => GalleryModel.formJson(json))
```

try it this way :

```dart
.map<GalleryModel>((gallery) => GalleryModel.formJson(gallery))
```

**EDIT**

Moreover, based on your response:

[image: Response]

I see no `category` field, however you are trying to map your `category` with `json['category']`. The only thing to category is `categories_id` and `categories`, maybe you meant `json['categories']` ?

Comment: its still like that, i already try to comment 1 by 1 code, the error say the same think

Comment: i found the problem is in category line code, should i provide to you the model ?

Comment: Well try checking everywhere you expect a `Map<String,dynamic>`. Intead of my provided fix, seems like `json['category']` can be `null`.

Comment: i have try to print my response.body, the data is shown but that strange its still null variable https://i.imgur.com/lK8oac4.png

Comment: @MzCoder editted my answer.

Comment: thanks mate that work, i need more focus